# Ruby on Rails: Send email from show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionmailer

I am a Rails noob and have a problem sending an email from a show page. There are several contact form tutorials out there but I cannot find one where I send an email from a page like a 'show' page. I have big errors in my routes I believe. In the model I state that Users have several Promotions and on the promotions show page I want to allow the current_user to send an email to @user.

here is app/mailers/quote_mailer.rb

```
class QuoteMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "tim@example.com"

  def quote_mail(promotion)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "You have an inquiry homeboy!")
  end 
end
```

In promotions_controller I put this action which I think might be wrong:

```
def quotedeliver
  QuoteMailer.quote_mail.deliver
  flash[:notice] = 'report sent!'
  redirect_to root_path # or wherever
end
```

Here is the form that I use to send the email (the :url is probably wrong but I dont know how it should look)

```
<%= form_for quote_mail, :url => quotedeliver_promotion_path(promotion), :html => {:method => :put } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I would love some help with this. I cannot find anything like it on stackoverflow, I have been trying for days. Thank you!

Comment: Whats the error you are getting..

Comment: what is your smtp settings in development.rb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing the route in config/routes.rb

you can define it like

```
post '/quotedeliver_promotion' => 'promotions#quotedeliver', :as => quotedeliver_promotion
```

Note that quotedeliver has to be rewritten quote_deliver to follow ruby syntax conventions. When you call

```
QuoteMailer.quote_mail.deliver
```

You are not giving the parameter, so try this

```
QuoteMailer.quote_mail(current_user).deliver
```

And change your method with

```
def quote_mail(user)
  mail ....
end
```

and you are all good

Comment: Thanks for the answer Albandiguer! I am getting NoMethodError in Promotions#show undefined method `quote_deliver_promotions_path' this is the form. I would love your help!                       <%= form_for @quote_mail, :url => quote_deliver_promotions_path(@user), :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
             <%= f.text_area :body %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>

Comment: Hi, you can submit this form using POST. so remove :html => {:method => :put}, If you defined the route as i told, the path is quotedeliver_promotion_path, no parameter. The user is given to the model in the controller

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent screen casts (through Railscasts) regarding sending e-mail http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=28.

One last thing, do not attach your mail sending method to a show action (if you are doing currently), the reason is show action is only for view something and users might be refreshing that page, So if you attach a mailer to that, mails might go out for each refresh.

Comment: thanks for this tip... based on this info i think this means that I am going to use a jquery modal to show the mail form which will exist on another page.

Answer (score 0):

```
def quote_mail(promotion)
   @user = user
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "You have an inquiry homeboy!")
end
```

from where you are access user variable, it should be promotion i think.